# Alterar atributo no Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-charts

Queria saber se tem como modificar os atributos de um `charts` do Google com um Jquery.
Exemplo:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'teste',
      pieHole: 0.4,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if( $(window).width() < 500){

      Alterar aqui!!!!
  }

  });
```

Queria mudar título lá em `var options` por exemplo.

Comment: você não vai conseguir modificar a variável dentro de uma função, devido ao escopo da função. Você deve definir a variável `options` fora de `google.load`. Leitura recomendada http://javascriptbrasil.com/2013/10/12/entenda-closures-no-javascript-com-facilidade/

Comment: ok, mas como eu altero o var options dentro do if?

Comment: `options.title = 'novo valor';`

Comment: Fiz esta alteração e não funcionou.

Comment: O que estou tentando fazer e deixar o charts responsivo. quando a tela for menor que 500 ele altere algum elemento de dentro do charts. estou usando o titulo como exemplo

Answer (score 0):

Para deixar o gráfico responsivo você deve chamar a função `resizeCharts()` dentro da função `drawChart()`.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'teste',
      pieHole: 0.4,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    function resizeCharts() {
      // redraw charts, dashboards, etc here
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    $(window).resize(resizeCharts);
}
```